# Count how many initial elements in Pandas Series equal to a certain value?

Tags: python, pandas, series

As in question. I know how to compute it, but is there better/faster/more elegant way to do this?
Cnt is the result.

```
s = pd.Series( np.random.randint(2, size=10) )
cnt = 0
for n in s:
        if n != 0:
            break
        else:
            cnt += 1
            continue
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) to create a `boolean mask` then use [`Series.cummin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummin.html) to return a cummulative minimum over this series finally use [`Series.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html) to get the total count:

```
cnt = s.eq(0).cummin().sum()
```

Example:

```
np.random.seed(9)
s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(2, size=10))

# print(s)
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    0
5    0
6    1
7    0
8    1
9    1
dtype: int64

cnt = s.eq(0).cummin().sum()
#print(cnt)
3
```

Comment: In case s = pd.Series( [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] ) it returns 0, while 10  would be desired behavior. Is it feasible?

Answer (score 2):

I have done in a dataframe as it is easier to produce but you can use the vectorized `.cumsum` to speed up your code with `.loc` for values == 0. Then just find the length with `len`:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
s = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(np.random.randint(2, size=10)))
s['t'] = s[0].cumsum()
o = len(s.loc[s['t']==0])
o
```

If you set `o` = to a column with `s['o'] = o`, then the output looks like this:

```
    0   t   o
0   0   0   2
1   0   0   2
2   1   1   2
3   1   2   2
4   0   2   2
5   1   3   2
6   1   4   2
7   1   5   2
8   1   6   2
9   0   6   2
```

Comment: Another method with cumsum: `s.cumsum().eq(0)[::-1].idxmax()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cumsum()` in a mask and then `sum()` to get the number of initial 0s in the sequence:

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(2, size=10))
(s.cumsum() == 0).sum()
```

Note that this method only works if you want to count 0s. If you want to count occurrences of non-zero values you can generalize it, ie.:

`(s.sub(s[0]).cumsum() == 0).sum()`